# python search json for nested key value and also get the path

Tags: python, json, path, nested

Looking for a good solution to find a value of a key which is known but the position is not known.
Here is the given .json, how would i find `"drops"` of `"name": "IQasSF"`?

I know to directly access it
And also what to have the path to it, any ideas?
for the first part

```
drops = next((e["drops"] for v in json.values() for e in v if e["name"] == "IQasSF"), "not found")
```

should work to find the key. but how get the path?

```
k.json={
  "Gadsh": [
    {
      "name": "ADGSET",
      "drops": [ 0.168, 0.054, 0.145, 0.3, 0.299873 ],
      "min_limits": [ -124, -134, -139, -359 ],
      "max_limits": [ 124, 134, 9, 359 ],
      "togo": [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
      "axis_flip": "0000"
    }
  ],
  "Ragar": [
  {
      "name": "660BB_IB",
      "drops": [ 0.800, 0.300, 1.280, 1.350, 0.260, 0.247 ],
      "min_limits": [ -180, -42, -20, -300 ],
      "max_limits": [ 180, 85, 120, 300 ],
      "link3_X_Min": -20,
      "link3_X_Max": 120,
      "togo": [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
      "axis_flip": "1000"
    }
  ],
  "Kulla": [
  {
      "name": "IR67_0s0_150_320",
      "drops": [ 0.780, 0.320, 1.280, 0.200, 1.5925, 0.200 ],
      "min_limits": [ -170, -65, -180, -300, -130, -360 ],
      "max_limits": [ 170, 85, 70, 300, 130, 360 ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name": "IQasSF",
      "drops": [ 0.780, 0.320, 1.280, 0.200, 1.5925, 0.200 ],
      "min_limits": [ -170, -65, -180, -300, -130, -360 ],
      "max_limits": [ 170, 85, 70, 300, 130, 360 ]
    }
  ]
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```py
counter = 0
for i in k["Kulla"]:    
    if i["name"] == "IQasSF":
        break
    counter += 1
print(k["Kulla"][counter])
```

It will iterate through the JSON Array and count until the key is found. Then the counter will be the position in the JSON Array.

Comment: We don't know where IQasSF is so we first need a search and than the path.
'''
drops = next((e["drops"] for v in json.values() for e in v if e["name"] == "IQasSF"), "not found")
'''
Works for search

Comment: can you try to ask it a bit different because I don't understand where the problem is sorry

Comment: This is just a small part of the .json, first step is to get the drops of a specific Name and than i would need to know in which section it is. Ragar, Gadsh or Kulla.
Your solution is just working if it is in Kulla, but this we do not know.